# C# Extracting JSON data

Tags: c#, json

My code here to get data from Wikipedia:

```
string URL = $"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=&titles={query}&redirects=1";

WebRequest wrREQUEST;
wrREQUEST = WebRequest.Create(URL);
wrREQUEST.Proxy = null;
wrREQUEST.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = wrREQUEST.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(responseData);
var jsonQuery = jsonData["query"];
string pageID = (string)jsonQuery;
```

But I keep getting

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

and the json data looks like this:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "31717":{
            "pageid":31717,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"United Kingdom"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also want to know since `"pages":{"31717":{}}` is an ID which I will not know in advance, how can I get that `31717` from enumerating the data?

Comment: Asked multiple times, use dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json deserialize from wikipedia api with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150997/json-deserialize-from-wikipedia-api-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find resolution of yout request, it might be possible that some time u will not get the first element value and it will trigger some exception.

Please replace your line :

**string pageID = (string)jsonQuery;**

with

```
**var jToken = jsonQuery["pages"].First;
            if (jToken != null)
            {
                string pageID = ((JProperty) jToken).Name;
            }**
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to explicitly convert `JObject` into a `string`, which is not possible using conversion, only by using Serilization.

But I understand you actually want the "PageId", which by the json structure, look like you need to take the "first key" from the response.
(Actually there are more ways)

So instead of

```
string pageID = (string)jsonQuery;
```

One possible way, will be using this

```
((JProperty)jsonQuery["pages"].First()).Name
```